# extract multiple variable type from txt file and use them in another method

Tags: java, file, static-methods

how can I use a static method to extract information and store it in order to use these data in another static method? There are more than one variable type in the file so I probably cannot simply return one variable type.

Comment: Of course that's possible, if you know how the data is formatted in the file.

Comment: You could have the method store the values in static variables.

Comment: This question is too general.
At the very least you should provide some example input and matching expected output.

Comment: I do know the format of the file. Can you be more specific about how to do it? For example, if the file is formatted as two integers followed by a new line of Strings, how can I store them separately? @Stultuske

Comment: read it line by line, decide for each line what it is, and map it to the correct type.

Comment: So you mean declare static variables in the class and use these variable names to store data in the file? Would I be able to use these in another static method? @Turamarth

Comment: But how can I use these data in another static method? @Stultuske

Comment: By passing them as parameters to that method, or by storing them in a scope which is accessible to that method. Either way, this is basic material, if you don't know how to do this, you really shouldn't be working with IO material, but first learn the basics